# Value of k for which the system is inconsistent

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Determine the   value   of  *k* for which   the system  is  **inconsistent**,   if  no  such    value   exists  state   that.

$\begin{cases}5x + 7y = -15\\
–x + ky = 3\end{cases}$

Solution: No    such    *k* exists.

Why is there no *k*? How can you determine this?

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at [Consistent_and_inconsistent_equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_and_inconsistent_equations)

Comment: Are you familiar with matrices?

Comment: Add $5$ times the second equation to the first, and solve for $y$.

Comment: @Dave Yes I'm familiar with matrices.

Comment: @saulspatz Then I have 12y=0 and thus y = 0 because 0/12=0. Is this correct?

Comment: Sorry, it's not correct.  You should have $(7+5k)y=0$.  Still, no matter what $k$ is, you can take $y=0$.  Then what?

Comment: @saulspatz Sorry, I don't understand it. I know that an inconsistent system of equations has no solutions, thus e.g. 0 = 5. But I still don't undertand how to determine if such k exists or not. Could you explain it a bit more? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the system of equations $$\begin{cases}a_1x + b_1y = c_1\\
a_2x + b_2y = c_2\end{cases}\tag1$$
It has a **unique solution** if and only if $~\dfrac{a_1}{a_2}\ne\dfrac{b_1}{b_2}~$.

It has an **infinitely many solutions** if and only if $~\dfrac{a_1}{a_2}=\dfrac{b_1}{b_2}=\dfrac{c_1}{c_2}~$.

> A system of equations is said to be **consistent** if it has at least one solution.

In the above two cases the system is consistent.

It has **no solution** if and only if $~\dfrac{a_1}{a_2}=\dfrac{b_1}{b_2}\ne\dfrac{c_1}{c_2}~$.

In the above case the system is inconsistent.

---

---

Here the system of equation is $$\begin{cases}5x + 7y = -15\\
–x + ky = 3\end{cases}\tag 2$$

The system is inconsistent, if

$~\dfrac{5}{-1}=\dfrac{7}{k}\ne\dfrac{-15}{3}~\implies ~-5=\dfrac{7}{k}\ne -5~$

There is no $~k~$ for which the above condition is satisfied.

Hence there is no value of k for which the system is inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

To say that the system is inconsistent is to say that there are no values of $x$ and $y$ that satisfy it.  If we add $5$ times the second equation to the first, we get $$(7+5k)y = 0$$  No matter what the value of $k$ is, we can take $y=0$ to satisfy the equation.  Substituting into the first equation, we find $x=-3$.  Now we can check that $x=-3, y=0$ satisfy both equations, no matter what the value of $k$ is.  That is, no value of $k$ makes the system inconsistent.